# Using Flex what event is fired when loading the popup defined in my layer tag?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, popup

Here is my Config.xml

...snip...

```
    <layer label="Pop-up (turn on/off)" type="dynamic" visible="true"  
        alpha="0.8"  
        url="xxx.xxx.xxx">  
        <sublayer id="0" popupconfig="popups/Parcels.xml"/>  -->
    
    </layer> 
</operationallayers>
```

So, when I click a point on the map a popup appears. That popup displays information about a parcel that was clicked, provides a "zoom to" button.

What event fired to make that occur?  I'd like to heavily customize what occurs when I click the map.  Bonus points if you can verify which object is being used to render the popup

### Parcels.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration>
    <title></title>
    
       <description>
        <![CDATA[Account# <b>{Strap}</b><br>Owner: <b>{Name1}</b><br>Address: <b>{Locn} {Locd} {Locs}</b><br><br><b>**2014 Values**</b><br>Just(Market)Value: <b>${Just}</b><br>Land Value: <b>${Land_Val}</b><br>Improvement Value: <b>${Improvemt}</b><br>Assessed Value: <b>${Assessed}</b><br><br>Homestead(x=yes): <b>{Homestead}</b><br>Land Sq Ft: <b>{Lsqft}</b><br>Total Building Area: <b>{GrossArea}</b><br>Total Living Area: <b>{Living}</b><br>Year Built: <b>{Yrbl}</b><br><br><a href="http://www.sc-pa.com/testsearch/parcel/details?STRAP={ACCOUNT}"><b>Additional Information</b></a><br>]]>
    </description>

    
    
    <fields>
        <field name="Strap"/>  Used in title, do not repeat in content
                
        <field name="Yrbl" alias="Year Built">
            <format usethousandsseparator="false"/>
        </field>
       
        <field name="Land_Val" percision = "2"> 
            <format usethousandsseparator="true"/>
        </field>
        <field name="Improvemt" percision = "2"> 
            <format usethousandsseparator="true"/>
        </field>
        <field name="Just" percision = "2"> 
            <format usethousandsseparator="true"/>
        </field>
        <field name="Assessed" percision = "2"> 
            <format usethousandsseparator="true"/>
        </field>
        <field name="Lsqft" percision = "2"> 
            <format usethousandsseparator="true"/>
        </field>
        <field name="GrossArea" percision = "2"> 
            <format usethousandsseparator="true"/>
        </field>
        <field name="Living" percision = "2"> 
            <format usethousandsseparator="true"/>
        </field>
        
        <field name="SALE_DATE">
            <format dateformat="shortDate"/>
        </field>   
    </fields>    

 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you using the esri flex viewer app? Then I would look at the .mxml file for the popups, I think it is called InfoPopup.mxml, or possibly it uses a custom skin

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to change an event that occurs when you click, you need to be in the mxml of your project.  So you need to have your code un-compiled in flashbuilder, but it looks like the mxml, whatever its called in your project  - edited